# Populate numpy array according to predefined array values

Tags: python, numpy

I have an A array where some indexes are populated with ones, the other values are nans.

A:       [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   1.   1.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   1.   1.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   1.  nan  nan  nan  nan   1.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]

type(A): class 'numpy.ndarray'

Is there a way to increment values after the ones (without using any kind of loops, only with filtering, indexing and broadcasting) and get this resulting B array:

B:       [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   1.   1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  10.  11.  12.   1.   1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.   1.  2.
  3.  4.  5.   1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.  16.  17.  18.  19  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep:

```
B = np.ones_like(A)
ons, = np.where(A==1)
if ons.size:
    B[:ons[0]] = np.nan
    if ons.size > 1:
        B[ons[1:]] -= np.diff(ons)
    B[ons[0]:] = B[ons[0]:].cumsum()
B
# array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,
#         6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,
#         6.,  7.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,
#         7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19.,
#        20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32.,
#        33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39.])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for your answer and for the effectiveness of your code!